# Stored procedure not returning records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this Stored Procedure which is not returning any records while the SELECT statement in it is working just fine. Running the SP like this:

```
CALL get_due_amount('654321');
```

returns nothing. No errors are shown.
What is wrong with this Stored Procedure? Txs.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_due_amount`(
  IN `_booking_ref_no` VARCHAR(50))
    NO SQL

SELECT 
  ph.booking_id, 
  Cast(SUM(ph.amount) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) as  paid, 
  b.booking_total, 
  b.booking_ref_no,
  (b.booking_total - SUM(ph.amount)) as due
FROM `i_payments_history` ph JOIN
     pt_bookings b on b.booking_id = ph.booking_id    
WHERE b.booking_ref_no LIKE '_booking_ref_no'
GROUP BY b.booking_id;
```

Comment: GROUP BY b.booking_id to GROUP BY ph.booking_id

Comment: i have changed that but stil no result

Comment: `LIKE '%_booking_ref_no%'`

Comment: i had already tryed that LIKE '%_booking_ref_no%'  but not working

Comment: Stored procedure should have BEGIN and END and after END you should close your delimiter like END// take a look [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html)

Comment: What type is _booking_ref_no?

Comment: can you try  "EXEC" instead of "CALL"

Comment: @Mihai data type is varchar(50)

Comment: @AymanBarhoum EXEX also not working

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic i am trying your suggestiong

Comment: AleksandarMiladinovic i have added BEGIN adn END wich is fine but adding END// throughs this error:   MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 10

Comment: Try: `... WHERE b.booking_ref_no LIKE CONCAT('%', \`_booking_ref_no\`, '%') ...`.

Comment: @wchiquito i tryed that also but gives this error: 
`#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: it would be good if you show us some sample date maybe you don't have any value in b.booking_ref_no which contain part like booking_ref_no! Take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55dcf0/1) that's example how you should create SP.. are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: @AleksandarMiladinovic yes i am using phpmyadmin, i guarantee you that the values that must be returned are present in field booking_ref_no cause if i jus runt the SELECT statemt i get back what i need, about making store procedures i have taken a look at the sql fiddle but on my side it gives an error if is use END//  without // is going fine